# Knockout js Grid view Is not showing up

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i am new to Knockout.js. I was trying to execute the following code to see the grid view of data. i took most of the code from Official Knockout website examples. but console in google shows error!! output is blank.Any suggestions?
The data array  is passed as parameter in the pageGridModel().

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>       
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML  4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-     8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'>
    </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var initialdata=[
                             {name:"aaaa1",price : 101,sales :110},  
                             {name:"aaaa2",price : 102,sales :210}, 
                             {name:"aaaa3",price : 103,sales :310}, 
                             {name:"aaaa4",price : 104,sales :410}, 
                             {name:"aaaa5",price : 105,sales :510}, 
                             {name:"aaaa6",price : 106,sales :610}, 
                             {name:"aaaa7",price : 107,sales :710}, 
                             ];
            var pageGridModel= function(items){
                   this.items=ko.observableArray(items);
                   this.addItem=function(){
                                              this.items.push({name:"aaaa1",price : 101,sales :110});
                                          };
                   this.sortItem=function(){
                                             this.items.sort();
                                          };
                   this.jumpToFirstPage=function(){
                                                 this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
                                          };
                   this.gridViewModel =new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
                      data :this.items,
                      columns:[{headerText:"NAME"  ,rowText:"name"},
                               {headerText:"PRICE" ,rowText:"price"},
                               {headerText:"SALES" ,rowText:"sales"},
                              ],
                              pageSize:4
                  });                          
            };
            ko.applyBindings(new pageGridModel(initialdata));
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel>  i mentioned it. In the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `knockout.simpleGrid.1.3.js` script reference in your head tag. simpleGrid is an optional plugin that is not included with the main KO library.

Here is it working in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygf1fpd1/3/).

```
<div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'>
</div>
```

Comment: <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel> i mentioned it.Still it has got some issues. Can you suggest a better approach.

Comment: @amali i am not sure what you are asking, the provided jsfiddle has no issues. Please clarify.